# jquery datatables and bootstrap issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using bootstrap and jquery datatables together.
When the datatables are rendered they leave spaces above and below.
Initally in those spaces there was search bar feature (above) and pagination feature (below). Later I disabled these options, now they dont appear any more but still I can see occupied space for them`

```
    <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                <div class="widget-header widget-header-flat widget-header-small">
                    <h5>Over All Summary</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="widget-body">
                    <div class="widget-main">
                        <div>
                      <table id="example" style='text-align: center' class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Customer Group</th>
                                <th># of Customer Contacted</th>
                                <th># of Customer Responded</th>
                                <th>Response Rate</th>
                                <th>Revenue (AED)</th>
                                <th>AMS</th>
                                <th>%Customer</th>
                                <th>%Revenue</th>
                                <th style='color:#47d147'>Shopping Frequency</th>
                                <th style='color:#47d147'>ATV</th>
                                <th style='color:#47d147'>UPT</th>
                                <th style='color:#47d147'>PPI</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td> 
                                    <i class="toggle" id='data1'>+</i> Tiger Nixon
                                </td>
                                <td>System Architect</td>
                                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                <td>61</td>
                                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                <td>$320,800</td>
                                <td>18thFEb,1990</td>
                                <td>No</td>
                                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                <td>$320,800</td>
                                <td>18thFEb,1990</td>
                                <td>No</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="data1_hidden hidden_data" style='display:none;' >
                                    <td> Tiger Nixon </td>
                                    <td>Hidden1</td>
                                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                    <td>61</td>
                                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                    <td>$320,800</td>
                                    <td>18thFEb,1990</td>
                                    <td>No</td>
                                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                    <td>$320,800</td>
                                    <td>18thFEb,1990</td>
                                    <td>No</td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr class="data1_hidden hidden_data" style='display:none;' >
                                    <td> Tiger Nixon </td>
                                    <td>Hidden1</td>
                                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                    <td>61</td>
                                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                    <td>$320,800</td>
                                    <td>18thFEb,1990</td>
                                    <td>No</td>
                                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                    <td>$320,800</td>
                                    <td>18thFEb,1990</td>
                                    <td>No</td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr class="data1_hidden hidden_data" style='display:none;' >
                                    <td> Tiger Nixon </td>
                                    <td>Hidden1</td>
                                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                    <td>61</td>
                                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                    <td>$320,800</td>
                                    <td>18thFEb,1990</td>
                                    <td>No</td>
                                     <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                    <td>$320,800</td>
                                    <td>18thFEb,1990</td>
                                    <td>No</td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td> 
                                    <i class="toggle" id='data2'>+</i> Tiger Nixon
                                </td>
                                <td>System Architect2</td>
                                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                <td>61</td>
                                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                <td>$320,800</td>
                                <td>18thFEb,1990</td>
                                <td>No</td>
                                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                <td>$320,800</td>
                                <td>18thFEb,1990</td>
                                <td>No</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="data2_hidden hidden_data" style='display:none'>
                                    <td> Tiger Nixon </td>
                                    <td>Hidden2</td>
                                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                    <td>61</td>
                                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                    <td>$320,800</td>
                                    <td>18thFEb,1990</td>
                                     <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                    <td>$320,800</td>
                                    <td>18thFEb,1990</td>
                                    <td>No</td>
                                    <td>No</td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                <td> 
                                    <i class="toggle" id='data3'>+</i> Tiger Nixon
                                </td>
                                <td>System Architect2</td>
                                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                <td>61</td>
                                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                <td>$320,800</td>
                                <td>18thFEb,1990</td>
                                <td>No</td>
                                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                <td>$320,800</td>
                                <td>18thFEb,1990</td>
                                <td>No</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="data3_hidden hidden_data" style='display:none'>
                                    <td> Tiger Nixon </td>
                                    <td>Hidden2</td>
                                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                    <td>61</td>
                                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                    <td>$320,800</td>
                                    <td>18thFEb,1990</td>
                                    <td>No</td>
                                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                    <td>$320,800</td>
                                    <td>18thFEb,1990</td>
                                    <td>No</td>
                             </tr>

                             </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#example').DataTable({
                "ordering": false,
                "paging"  : true,
                "bInfo"   : false,
                "searching": true,
            });
})

</script>
```

` 
[Blue spaces on the top and bottom and when I inspect element I can see   added where as its not in my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyB8Q.jpg)

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Will be difficult for me as its a zend framework and will hard for me to replicate it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3tngxw82/

Comment: check the CSS of .dataTables_wrapper .row-fluid:first-child , there is padding and backgorund-color applied to this container.

Answer (score 0):

```
.dataTables_wrapper .row-fluid:first-child {paddding:0px}
```